# One sample t-test, unsure of test value

Tags: t-test, small-sample

I would like to use a one sample t-test where accuracy is 50-50..

The data is rated on a three point likert scale of 1-performed task incorrectly, 2 - performed task with minor mistakes, 3-performed task accurately

I have calculated the mean and standard deviation of my data and that is fine, I am just confused about what test value to use.. (newbie)

Do I use .5 as in 50% or do I use 1.5 as this is the center of the possible high score of 3 that can be achieved?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to know if it's 50-50?

Comment: I must confess I have no clear idea what this post is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

*(I'm not sure I understand your situation, after we get more information I can update this answer, if necessary.)*

I would not use a t-test to assess differences between groups in ratings on a single three-point Likert item.  Those data simply won't be appropriate for that test.  I might use the [Mann-Whitney U-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U).

However, I don't understand what you want to be 50%-50%.  You mention "accuracy", but state that your data are rated with three levels.  If only level 3 corresponds to 'accurate', and that is what you are really interested in, I would collapse levels 1 & 2 into a single *inaccurate* category and perform a [binomial test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test).  This will lend itself well to being compared to 50%-50%.  (Note that if you think only 1 is 'inaccurate', but either 2 or 3 can be considered *accurate*--albeit to varying degrees--you can do the same test, just collapse levels 2 & 3 instead.)

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer me. I only have one set of 10 participants and i am trying to see if they performed a task correctly with accuracy greater than a hypothetical accuracy of 50-50.. In a one sample ttest i would compare the mean of my participants 2.875 and standard deviation of .35355 against a population mean of 50% accuracy... I am confused about whether I use .5 as the population mean or if I use 1.5 due to the fact that 3 is the highest score a person can achieve (and 1.5 is half of 3).. So its just the mean I am comparing that is confusing me..

Comment: I cant use a Mann Whitney as I only have one group of participants.. However, a binomial test may be better but I was told to use a one sample t-test.. Is it bad to have 1-performed task incorrectly, 2 - performed task with minor mistakes, 3-performed task accurately? I could collapse the levels to just 1 and 2.. I am just unsure of what is statistically correct..

Comment: You cannot use a one-sample t-test in the way you describe for the data you have. That test is not appropriate for your data & your situation. If you want to know if the proportion of people who get a 3 is > 50%, collapse 1&2 into a single *inaccurate* category and conduct a binomial test. Whoever told you to use a 1 sample t-test didn't understand the nature of your situation / data.